# SQL query needs optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT LM.user_id,LM.users_lineup_id, min( LM.total_score ) AS total_score
FROM vi_lineup_master LM JOIN
     vi_contest AS C
     ON C.contest_unique_id = LM.contest_unique_id join
     (SELECT min( total_score ) as total_score
      FROM vi_lineup_master
      GROUP BY group_unique_id
     ) as preq
     ON LM.total_score = preq.total_score
 WHERE LM.contest_unique_id = 'iledhSBDO' AND
       C.league_contest_type = 1
 GROUP BY group_unique_id
```

Above query is to find the loser per group of game, query return accurate result but its not responding with large data. How can I optimize this?

Comment: Run a `explain` and post the query plan

Comment: Do you have indices setup on the join columns?

Comment: Add the **contest_unique_id = 'iledhSBDO'** into the inner subquery **preq**

Comment: And also indices on the columns in `where` clause

Comment: @StanislavL, and why so? I don't see any definite benefit

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY...

Comment: GROUP BY unique_id sounds like a paradoxum for me....

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff, perhaps `group_unique_id` is not unique in the tables of this query, but is a many-to-one reference to a column of the same name in some other table.

Comment: It is not mandatory here to accept answers, but it is certainly community-minded to do so. It looks like Felypp reminded you 18 months ago - would you consider doing this now? I can see you are signed in today.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move your `JOIN`s to subqueries. Also, you should pay attention on your "wrong" `GROUP BY` usage on the outer query. In Mysql you can group by some columns and select others not specified in the group clause without any aggregation function, but the database can't ensure what data it will return to you. For the sake of consistency of your application, wrap them in an aggregation function.

Check if this one helps:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(LM.user_id) AS user_id,
  MIN(LM.users_lineup_id) AS users_lineup_id, 
  MIN(LM.total_score) AS total_score
FROM vi_lineup_master LM 
WHERE 1=1
  -- check if this "contest_unique_id" is equals
  -- to 'iledhSBDO' for a "league_contest_type" valued 1
  AND LM.contest_unique_id IN
  (
    SELECT C.contest_unique_id
    FROM vi_contest AS C
    WHERE 1=1
      AND C.contest_unique_id = 'iledhSBDO'
      AND C.league_contest_type = 1
  )
  -- check if this "total_score" is one of the 
  -- "min(total_score)" from each "group_unique_id"
  AND LM.total_score IN
  (
    SELECT MIN(total_score) 
    FROM vi_lineup_master
    GROUP BY group_unique_id
  )
GROUP BY LM.group_unique_id
;
```

Also, some pieces of this query may seem redundant, but it's because I did not want to change the filters you wrote, just moved them.

Also, your query logic seems a bit strange to me, based on the tables/columns names and how you wrote it... please, check the comments in my query which reflects what I understood of your implementation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it did the job and working with more than 1 lac records as well.......................Thanks a lot Felypp :)  Thankyou all for your suggestions too (y)

Comment: @user3296832 You're welcome. Don't forget to accept any answer as the right one.